# Redirect non-www to www Results in Page isnt Redirecting Properly

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, web-config, redirect

I am trying to redirect non-www website to www but when i add redirect rule in my web.config or in my Global.asax it shows that page isn't redirecting properly. Redirect rule in web.config

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="testdomain\.com$" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.testdomain\.com$" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.testdomain.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

i have also tried this from Global.asax inside `Application_BeginRequest`
NOTE: i am trying one of these things at a time.

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("http://testdomain.com"))
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location",
    Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace("http://testdomain.com", "http://www.testdomain.com"));
}
```

My Default.aspx and Default.aspx.cs page has no code in it..
Any idea guys where the actual problem could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code this code under `<system.webServer>` section

```
<rewrite>
<rule name="Redirect to www">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: yes i am using one thing at a time. i tried web.config ruie first. then after i tried global.asax